# Default value in structure (char)

Tags: c++, struct, char, assign

i'd like to ask for a help.
When i got this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    unsigned char myBytes[5];
    MyStruct()
    {
        myBytes[0] = 0x89;
        myBytes[1] =  0x50;
        myBytes[2] =  0x4E;
        myBytes[3] =  0x47;
        myBytes[4] =  0x0D;
    }        
};
```

How to make it easies ?
like 
myBytes = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, you can do either of the following:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    unsigned char myBytes[5] = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D};     
};

// or...

struct MyStruct
{
    unsigned char myBytes[5];
    MyStruct() : myBytes{0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D}
    { }        
};
```

Otherwise, you've got the best method already.

Comment: none works for me, i'm using vistual studio 2012 and empty c++ project, and i've never heard about c++11/c++03 before, how can i work with c++11 or c++03 ?

Comment: [Neither is supported in VS 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). However, VS 2013 has support for both. Both GCC and clang are C++11 feature-complete.